# mysqld crashing, php processes remain in memory

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I had a database configured for collation utf8_unicode_ci but after a mysql database upgrade (the server was running an out-of-support version) the stored procedures that I use to interface with a desktop app would not run... kept saying that there was a collation conflict between implicit utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci.

So, I changed the schema and every single database to utf8_general_ci because another article on here recommended that would help.  It did, the stored procedures started working again.

But, now, for some reason, mysqld goes down (the logs say no room for buffer), and when I look at 'ps x -A' there are about 48-50 running php processes, and the website goes down with the no database error.

I have to killall -9 php and /etc/init.d/mysql start to get everything back up.  Simply starting mysql won't happen because the php processes are apparently eating up all the ram.

What have I done?

The desktop app is a windows app, it's used for order processing.  The server sits on a dedicated linux machine at hostgator, where the website sits.

Help?  I've tried very hard to resolve this problem, on my own.  I am currently running a cron process to perform the necessary tasks if mysqld goes away, but that doesn't resolve the underlying issue, which is what I would like to do.

Comment: php processes? as in you're running PHP as a cgi app, instead of embedded in the webserver?

Comment: Yes.  And the story behind that is a little long.  I did some homework and another stackoverflow article recommended that I do it that way because I'm running the website as the user, and when I attempted to run PHP embedded, it would not let me.  Apache failed to start.  

I admit, linux administration is not my strongest suit, but I've been able to get through it okay, except for these really vexing problems.  I'm mainly a developer. 

I can post my config if you like.

Comment: if you need to run php with different permissions than the webserver itself, there's suphp available for just such a thing.

Comment: Right, suphp is installed, that is what was causing the problem.

Comment: Okay.  I've been doing some digging, here, and it seems that php is spawning and spawning first, not mysqld dying.  Mysqld is dying because it's out of memory.

Is it possible that traffic to the site is just so taxing that it's having a hard time keeping up?

Comment: I have no clue what is going on.  

It seems to always happen after one specific event (a SOAP call to CallFire and an updated to the database to add the call record).

Then suddenly there's a litany of database cannot be opened errors from mysqli_connect... and these php instances start collecting in memory ... 

I have no idea what is going on here....

Comment: try running whatever query(ies?) being done by that soap call manually and see what happens. could be you've got a corrupted table or something.

Comment: Now I've cleaned up the code surrounding the CallFire call placing script to explicitly close the mysql session at the end of the script and before exiting.  That has cleared up that issue, somewhat. 

Now, I'm getting this in the logs:

[05-Dec-2013 18:14:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2004): Can't create TCP/IP socket (105) in /home/******/public_html/session_pic.php on line 42

That's actually inside my session_pic.php script, on the product list.  The odd thing is the products still appear.

Comment: We're on with the people, now.  There was only 768MB (yes, with an M) of memory, and she was getting 100 hits a second ... it seems to be that when the database coughs, the php glitches and stays in memory ... and then it turns into a sort of positive feedback of PHP and MySQL constantly trying to play catch up with each other.  That is what it SEEMS like is happening. 

Last resort, I'll dump the schema and data off site, and recreate the schema afresh under a different name and switch over.

Comment: This is my problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512399/php-cgi-processes-not-closed-off-after-script-finishes-executing-php5-3-3-win

I just don't know why it started all of a sudden.